# Handling Web Service Timeouts While Performing Long-Running Oracle Database Tasks

Tags: oracle, http, oracle10g, webserver

I'm having trouble with a long running webservice timing out in an Oracle 10g environment.

The client calls the webservice and after approximately 10 minutes, it receives the following response:

> HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable Server:
>   OracleAS-Web-Cache-10g/10.1.2.3.0 Content-Type: text/html Connection:
>   Keep-Alive Keep-Alive: timeout=600, max=999 Content-Length: 402
>
> No
>   Response from Application Web Server
>
> ## No Response from Application
>   Web Server
>
> There was no response from the application web
>   server for the page you requested. 
> Please notify the site's
>   webmaster and try your request again later.
>
> ---

The webservice executes a procedure in the database which takes a long time to finish (more than 20 min, on average) and the client receives the above response after aproximately 10 minutes.

My guess is that the webserver thinks the webservice has crashed, so it terminates it and sends the above response to the client.

My question is: how do I deactivate the timeout setting? I need to let the webservice run for as long as it needs (or, at least, for severeal hours).

I don't have access to the webserver's configuration or administration console but I can ask the guys responsible for managing it to change any setting (this is a test environment).

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: I assume this webservice is used internally only?

Comment: Architecturally, why are you designing a synchronous web service call when you expect the call to take this long?  Normally, you would design the system so that the web service call returns immediately when the job is queued to run and then provide a callback to notify the client when the results are ready.

Comment: #tbone

Yes, this is used internally only.

Comment: #Justin Cave

This is an old application which has been working for years in a productive environment. I can't redesign it.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue. I am facing same kind of issue. How did you fix it ?